# Parsing excel files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel

In my ios application i am trying to parse the excel file given by the user and do something with the data later on.. which i dint decided yet.. I have searched about how to parse excel file in iOS, and find that many are saying convert the excel file to csv file and parse that, i also find a framework DHlibxls and tried using it, after cloning it from github, it has also given a test project on how to parse excel files and it is also working fine, but the problem is in that test project i tried to replace the existing test.xls file with another test file then after i tried to run it gave an exception and the app crashed.[image]

the new file i added is .xlsx file, so i thought that may be it wont read the .xlsx file , so then i tried to add a small .xls file but still the exception occured, after that i tried to add the same test file given in the folder but by changing the name to test2.xls, but the exception is still there. I cant understand the problem.

Many are saying that convert the .xls file to .csv file, how to convert it in ios , is there a library or method in ios to convert the .xls file to .csv dynamically while the app is running..Thank you

Comment: log path ,using finder check the file exist in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding a file make sure that it's membership is checked as in the below screen.

[image]

Or for existing files in xcode do the following to add it in the target. Select the file and check the file inspector and then check the target membership.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have missed the basic steps and working for an answer nearly about 3 hrs.

Comment: I hope you will remember it and next time it will take your not more than 3 minutes to figure it out. Everyone wastes his/her hours just because of this silly mistakes.

Comment: When i tried to import that framework, it is not working, what i mean is when i tried to import the file DHxlsReader.h in my project, it is saying no file found, i have followed all the step for adding the framwork to project in the link http://pymatics.com/2011/12/23/tutorial-develop-a-private-framework-for-your-mac-app-using-xcode-4s-workspace-feature/

Comment: Try again the tutorial, the problem is with header search path (not sure). If still exists the ask another question. I hope someone might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XlsxReaderWriter](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter) library...It is free and usefull for read & write!

- Create a new project or open an existing project
- Insert XlsxReaderWriter.xcodeproj as a sub project of your project
- In your target Build phases insert XlsxReaderWriter as a target dependency
- Add libXlsxReaderWriter.a and libz.tbd in Link binary with Libraries. Older systems can use libz.dylib instead of libz.tbd.
- Add -all_load in Linking / Other Linker Flags in your project settings
- Add the XlsxReaderWriter root directory path to User Header Search Paths and set it as recursive. For example, set the path to "$(SRCROOT)/XlsxReaderWriter/", not "$(SRCROOT)/XlsxReaderWriter/XlsxReaderWriter/".

*Now, you can import BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.h in your code.*

It also supports Swift:

Comment: is this library free?

Answer (score -1):

but it take too much time read data in xlsx.